# Grails 2 app wont deploy on JBOSS: BeanCreationException

Tags: grails, jboss, jboss5.x, grails-2.0

After having upgraded one of my apps from Grails 1.3.7 to 2.1.0 and installed a couple of additional plugins the app will no longer deploy on JBOSS AS 5.1, which is used for production.
The error I am getting from the JBOSS server log is the following:

```
13:39:10,263 ERROR [[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
            org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings, but interface was expected
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:126)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:153)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:170)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:121)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:104)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4393)
```

In order to resolve another issue I had earlier on( LifecycleException/ReflectionException: Cannot find method addChild...) I have introduced a jboss-classloading.xml into my WEB-INF directory. At the current moment this has the following contents:

```
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0" name="ROOT.war" domain="DefaultDomain" top-level-classloader="true" export-all="NON_EMPTY" import-all="true" parent-first="false"> </classloading>
```

I suspect that the current issue is also class-loading related, especially since I see that the class in question is being loaded from JBOSS lib folder, and not from the jars in the war's lib folder:

```
 [Loaded org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings from jar:file:/usr/local/jboss-5.1.0.GA/common/lib/hibernate-core.jar!/]
```

Apparently the class org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings exists both in hibernate-core.jar as well as inside the app's lib folder(hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar). I have therefore tried to tweak the jboss-classloading.xml file in different ways in order to force JBOSS to load this specific class from within the war file, but no matter what I do I keep getting the same error (or different ones much earlier in the deploy cycle).

The full contents of my war's WEB-INF/lib dir:

```
activation-1.1.jar                        google-collections.jar                     h2-1.3.164.jar                                 sitemesh-2.4.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar                           grails-bootstrap-2.1.0.jar                 hamcrest-all-1.1.jar                           smartsprites-0.2.1.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar                       grails-core-2.1.0.jar                      hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar  spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
asm-3.1.jar                               grails-crud-2.1.0.jar                      hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar                spring-asm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
aspectjrt-1.6.10.jar                      grails-datastore-core-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar    hibernate-ehcache-3.6.10.Final.jar             spring-aspects-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
aspectjweaver-1.6.10.jar                  grails-datastore-gorm-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar    hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar          spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar                grails-datastore-simple-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar  hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar            spring-binding-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar
axis-1.4.jar                              grails-hibernate-2.1.0.jar                 javase-1.7.jar                                 spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar                       grails-logging-2.1.0.jar                   javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar                        spring-context-support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
axis-saaj-1.4.jar                         grails-plugin-codecs-2.1.0.jar             javassist-3.7.ga.jar                           spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar                     grails-plugin-controllers-2.1.0.jar        jcaptcha-all-1.0-RC6.jar                       spring-expression-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
cas-client-core-3.2.1.jar                 grails-plugin-converters-2.1.0.jar         jstl-1.1.2.jar                                 spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
cglib-2.2.jar                             grails-plugin-datasource-2.1.0.jar         jta-1.1.jar                                    spring-jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar               grails-plugin-domain-class-2.1.0.jar       jul-to-slf4j-1.6.2.jar                         spring-js-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar
commons-codec-1.5.jar                     grails-plugin-filters-2.1.0.jar            logkit-1.0.1.jar                               spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar             grails-plugin-gsp-2.1.0.jar                mail-1.4.3.jar                                 spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4.jar                      grails-plugin-i18n-2.1.0.jar               mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar                 spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
commons-discovery-0.2.jar                 grails-plugin-log4j-2.1.0.jar              ognl-2.7.3.jar                                 spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
commons-el-1.0.jar                        grails-plugin-mimetypes-2.1.0.jar          oro-2.0.8.jar                                  spring-webflow-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar              grails-plugin-scaffolding-2.1.0.jar        pjl-comp-filter-1.7.jar                        spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
commons-io-2.1.jar                        grails-plugin-services-2.1.0.jar           quartz-1.6.1.jar                               tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.27.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar                      grails-plugin-servlets-2.1.0.jar           quartz-2.1.5.jar                               tomcat-embed-core-7.0.27.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar                   grails-plugin-tomcat-2.1.0.jar             selenium-java-client-driver-1.0.2.jar          tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.27.jar
commons-pool-1.5.6.jar                    grails-plugin-url-mappings-2.1.0.jar       servlet-api-2.5.jar                            tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.27.jar
commons-validator-1.3.1.jar               grails-plugin-validation-2.1.0.jar         shiro-cas-1.2.0.jar                            tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.27.jar
concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.2_jdk5.jar  grails-resources-2.1.0.jar                 shiro-core-1.2.0.jar                           utils-0.0.2.jar
core-1.7.jar                              grails-spring-2.1.0.jar                    shiro-ehcache-1.2.0.jar                        validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar                           grails-web-2.1.0.jar                       shiro-quartz-1.2.0.jar                         xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
ecj-3.6.2.jar                             grails-webflow-2.1.0.jar                   shiro-spring-1.2.0.jar                         yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar
ehcache-core-2.4.6.jar                    groovy-all-1.8.6.jar                       shiro-web-1.2.0.jar
```

Does anyone have an idea about how to get around this issue?

Comment: Most like JBoss has another set of hibernate jars that are loading. You need to not load these jars for this webapp. I know how to do this in weblogic, but my JBoss fu is not that strong :(

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugins for this :)

http://grails.org/plugin/jbossas

The docs are located here:

http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-jbossas/

This is why this is happenning:

https://community.jboss.org/thread/156441

You will need to configure JBoss to exclude the hibernate jars.  The JBoss Hibernate jars that are in common/lib in the JBoss install are loading first, instead of the Grails Hibernate jars.  This is a classloader order / preference issue.

A very dirty solution is to remove the jars under common/lib or as recommended get the classloader working to exclude those jars.

Comment: Just learned about the jbossas plugin earlier today - think I have done all of the steps mentioned in its docs manually already, but could definitely have saved some time if I had learned about this plugin a bit earlier.

Comment: The link the jboss thread is excellent - gives some good insight to the inner workings of JBOSS classloading that I was not aware of despite days of research. Will try out one or more of the suggested approaches tomorrow - hopefully it will work :-)

Comment: I have now tried different variants of the suggested approach:
1) Installed jbossas plugin: Results in the same error as seen previously: LifecycleException:  Error initializaing :  javax.management.ReflectionException: Cannot find method addChild with this signature at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4150)
2)Tried step one of the steps suggested in https://community.jboss.org/message/730457#730457: Results in same LifecycleException as above.

Comment: Also tried 3) Removing the hibernate jars from ../jboss/common/lib: Results in ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jboss.web.deployment:war=/ROOT state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException (...)

- Would it be possible to point to a more specific configuration using jboss-web.xml and jboss-classloading.xml? 
This seems to be way more complicated to fix than I would have expected from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using JBoss 6.1 for a project.  We started on 1.3.7, then moved to 2.0.3 and are now on 2.1.

I never got that exact issue, nor have I experienced any conflicts with Hibernate, but we did experience conflicts with Quartz.

Here's what I use to isolate things...

I have this in /WEB-INF/jboss-scanning.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<scanning xmlns='urn:jboss:scanning:1.0'>
    <path name='WEB-INF/lib/grails-datastore-gorm-*.jar'>
        <include name='org.grails.datastore' />
    </path>
</scanning>
```

I have this in /WEB-INF/jboss-classloading.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<classloading
        xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
        domain="hotdesk.war"
        export-all="NON_EMPTY"
        import-all="true"
/>
```

And finally, I have this in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
dependencies {
    //Added to deal with problems running Quartz on JBoss
    //NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V]
    compile ('cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2')
}

//Added to deal with problems running Quartz on JBoss
//NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V]
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
    println "Removing export jars from WEB-INF/lib/"
    delete(file: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/cglib-2.2.jar")
}
```

Hope that gets you closer to resolving your issue.